# How to export filtered result from NonFactor.Mvc.Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using  NonFactor.Mvc.Grid for showing data in grid, and I want to export the filtered result to excel
but when using

```
grid.Query = new NameValueCollection(Request.QueryString);
```

below is the code for creating grid.

```
private IGrid<PersonModel> CreateExportableGrid()
{
IGrid<PersonModel> grid = new Grid<PersonModel>(PeopleRepository.GetPeople());
grid.Query = new NameValueCollection(Request.QueryString);

grid.Columns.Add(model => model.Name).Titled("Name");
grid.Columns.Add(model => model.Surname).Titled("Surname");

grid.Columns.Add(model => model.Age).Titled("Age");
grid.Columns.Add(model => model.Birthday).Titled("Birth date");
grid.Columns.Add(model => model.IsWorking).Titled("Employed");



return grid;
}
```

I am getting filtered result in View page, but when I try to export to excel, when using grid.Rows.Count(), I get all records regardless of filter.

```
IGrid<PersonModel> grid = CreateExportableGrid();
```

when using grid.Rows.Count() I can see all results regardless of filter.

if i add the pagination in creating grid in controller, I will get result, but the exported list will contain data in selected page number only, not the data in all pages.

How do I resolve this issue?
I am using ClosedXML for exporting to excel.

Comment: Please can you provide more code, an example of how to replicate the problem and describe the precise behaviour that is expected that isn't happening.

Comment: @Luke , edited my question.

Comment: Hey John, I believe you solved this, Please share the solution as I am facing the same problem.